# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

Tags: java, listview, bitmap, out-of-memory

So I've got a lazy image loader for my `ListView`. I also use [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue/823966#823966) for better memory management and have `SoftReference` Bitmap images stored in my `ArrayList`.

My `ListView` works loads 8 images from a DB then once the user scrolls all the way to the bottom it loads another 8 etc etc. There was no issue when there were around 35 images or less, but any more and my app Force Closes with `OutOfMemoryError`.

The thing that I can't understand is I have my code inside a try catch:

```
try
{
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length, o);

    //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;

    while(true)
    {
        if(width_tmp/2 < imageWidth || height_tmp/2 < imageHeight)
        {
            break;
        }

        width_tmp/=2;
        height_tmp/=2;
        scale++;
    }

    //Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length, o2);        
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But the try catch block isn't catching the `OutOfMemory` exception and from what I understand the `SoftReference` Bitmap images should be cleared when the application is running out of memory stopping the `OutOfMemory` exception being thrown.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OutOfMemoryError` is an error not an exception, you should not catch it.

see http://mindprod.com/jgloss/exception.html

EDIT: known problem see [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8488)

Comment: Ah my bad... didn't know that at all. Is there anything I can do to prevent it from happening? I'm completely stuck.

Comment: It makes perfectly good sense to catch OutOfMemoryError, if one has a way to resolve the problem, or if one wants to tell the user by for instance starting a new activity in a separate proces.

Answer (score 9):

I suppose may be this post will help you

```
//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Should be the select solution!

Answer (score 0):

Error and Exception are subclassed from Throwable.
Error are supposed to be so drastic, that you should not catch them.

But you can catch anything.

```
try
{ 
}
catch (Throwable throwable)
{
}
```