# Problem with big images ( java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget )

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, bitmapfactory

as a many people i have a problem with big images too. 
ok,here my code.  I found on stackoverflow how to fix this using BitmapFactory.Options.  But in my situations i get image not from file. Can anyone tell me how to do this with Bitmap which already created in memory ( i get this picture from camera on phone)

```
 public void getImageAndSend( )
  {

     Bitmap newbmp ;
         newbmp= Bitmap.createBitmap(oBmp.getWidth(), oBmp.getHeight(),oBmp.getConfig());////<----------error here
      log("widt oBmp = "+oBmp.getWidth());/// width = 2048
      log(" height oBmp = "+oBmp.getHeight());///height 1538
      //BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options(); // <----- it's possible to do it without `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathToFile,options) ?? 
      //options.inTempStorage = new byte[16*1024];
          Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newbmp);
          //code 
  System.gc();/// can't right understand but this line fixed this problem on emulator but not on real device
```

}

please tell me how to fix my problem ? : (
On emulator im not have this error. But on real device i see this error (bitmap size exceeds VM budget)
Regards, Peter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are getting image from camera,get the uri of the image you capture in onActivityResult() method as follows

```
Uri selectedImageUri=intent.getData();
String actualPath=getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
File file=new File(actualPath);
Bitmap bitmap=decodeFile(file); //this is new bitmap which you can use for your purpose 

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }


private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }
```

Hope this helps.This is the very familiar problem when u deal with high quality images taken from phone.check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956702/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget) out too

Comment: oBmp - my bitmap , which i get from byteArray, not from intent.     Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.length);   can i use options here ??

Comment: u said u r getting image from camera phone.aren't you?Then can u elobrate on wat u r doing from there on?Then why do u need to get it from byte array?

Comment: public void onPictureTaken(byte[] paramArrayOfByte, Camera paramCamera)
     {}

Comment: i try to do it with byteArray (not from file) and now i don't have error - but quality are very bad. Picture is blur.

Comment: @androidGuy I am getting null bitmap..??

Answer (score 0):

Here is my BitmpaHelper class that if OutOfMemoryError proof :-)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public class BitmapHelper
{

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    public static Bitmap decodeFile(File bitmapFile, int requiredWidth, int requiredHeight, boolean quickAndDirty)
    {
        try
        {
            //Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options bitmapSizeOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bitmapSizeOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(bitmapFile), null, bitmapSizeOptions);

            // load image using inSampleSize adapted to required image size
            BitmapFactory.Options bitmapDecodeOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bitmapDecodeOptions.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];
            bitmapDecodeOptions.inSampleSize = computeInSampleSize(bitmapSizeOptions, requiredWidth, requiredHeight, false);
            bitmapDecodeOptions.inPurgeable = true;
            bitmapDecodeOptions.inDither = !quickAndDirty;
            bitmapDecodeOptions.inPreferredConfig = quickAndDirty ? Bitmap.Config.RGB_565 : Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

            Bitmap decodedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(bitmapFile), null, bitmapDecodeOptions);

            // scale bitmap to mathc required size (and keep aspect ratio)

            float srcWidth = (float) bitmapDecodeOptions.outWidth;
            float srcHeight = (float) bitmapDecodeOptions.outHeight;

            float dstWidth = (float) requiredWidth;
            float dstHeight = (float) requiredHeight;

            float srcAspectRatio = srcWidth / srcHeight;
            float dstAspectRatio = dstWidth / dstHeight;

            // recycleDecodedBitmap is used to know if we must recycle intermediary 'decodedBitmap'
            // (DO NOT recycle it right away: wait for end of bitmap manipulation process to avoid
            // java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@416ee7d8
            // I do not excatly understand why, but this way it's OK

            boolean recycleDecodedBitmap = false;

            Bitmap scaledBitmap = decodedBitmap;
            if (srcAspectRatio < dstAspectRatio)
            {
                scaledBitmap = getScaledBitmap(decodedBitmap, (int) dstWidth, (int) (srcHeight * (dstWidth / srcWidth)));
                // will recycle recycleDecodedBitmap
                recycleDecodedBitmap = true;
            }
            else if (srcAspectRatio > dstAspectRatio)
            {
                scaledBitmap = getScaledBitmap(decodedBitmap, (int) (srcWidth * (dstHeight / srcHeight)), (int) dstHeight);
                recycleDecodedBitmap = true;
            }

            // crop image to match required image size

            int scaledBitmapWidth = scaledBitmap.getWidth();
            int scaledBitmapHeight = scaledBitmap.getHeight();

            Bitmap croppedBitmap = scaledBitmap;

            if (scaledBitmapWidth > requiredWidth)
            {
                int xOffset = (scaledBitmapWidth - requiredWidth) / 2;
                croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, xOffset, 0, requiredWidth, requiredHeight);
                scaledBitmap.recycle();
            }
            else if (scaledBitmapHeight > requiredHeight)
            {
                int yOffset = (scaledBitmapHeight - requiredHeight) / 2;
                croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, yOffset, requiredWidth, requiredHeight);
                scaledBitmap.recycle();
            }

            if (recycleDecodedBitmap)
            {
                decodedBitmap.recycle();
            }
            decodedBitmap = null;

            scaledBitmap = null;
            return croppedBitmap;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * compute powerOf2 or exact scale to be used as {@link BitmapFactory.Options#inSampleSize} value (for subSampling)
     * 
     * @param requiredWidth
     * @param requiredHeight
     * @param powerOf2
     *            weither we want a power of 2 sclae or not
     * @return
     */
    public static int computeInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean powerOf2)
    {
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        // Raw height and width of image
        final int srcHeight = options.outHeight;
        final int srcWidth = options.outWidth;

        if (powerOf2)
        {
            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.

            int tmpWidth = srcWidth, tmpHeight = srcHeight;
            while (true)
            {
                if (tmpWidth / 2 < dstWidth || tmpHeight / 2 < dstHeight)
                    break;
                tmpWidth /= 2;
                tmpHeight /= 2;
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) srcHeight / (float) dstHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) srcWidth / (float) dstWidth);

            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
            // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
            // requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

    public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable drawable)
    {
        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable)
        {
            return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);

        return bitmap;
    }

    public static Bitmap getScaledBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int newWidth, int newHeight)
    {
        int width = bitmap.getWidth();
        int height = bitmap.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

        // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

        // RECREATE THE NEW BITMAP
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
        return resizedBitmap;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem in my android app. When you decode a bitmap from a big sized image and set as imageBitmap to an image view probably your application will slow and after a few try you'll get an "out of memory exception"

You can use Universal Image Loader. https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

```
String url = "file://" + your_file_path_on_sd_card;
com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, ivPicture, options);
```