# Why does accessing Android MediaStore, using MonoDroid, generate UnauthorizedAccessException?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

When I attempt to use the solution presented on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693069/problem-with-big-images-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-bud) for dealing with large bitmaps in Android, I get an `UnauthorizedAccessException` at the point I'm trying to read from the file system from a location such as:

```
/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20111223_122513.jpg
```

Is there a particular permission in my *manifest* I was supposed to select, or something else going on?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is always this one:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If you're looking to display a screen-sized version of a full-resolution photograph, may I please refer you to the [Android Training article](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskScalePhoto) on this subject.

Comment: This permission is required for *reading* the file?  Odd.  I'll certainly give it a try.  I am indeed using a technique similar to the linked article - the exception happens in reading the file, such as when the sample does "BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);"